# Refinement of an Open Cover

Tags: smooth-manifolds

This seems rather simple, but just curious about the following definition (pulled from Lee, but definitely standard):

> Given an open cover $\mathcal{U}$ of $X$, another open cover $\mathcal{V}$ is called a refinement of $\mathcal{U}$ if for each $V\in \mathcal{V}$ there exists some $U\in \mathcal{U}$ such that $V\subset U$.

Why not the following definition:

> Given an open cover $\mathcal{U}$ of $X$, another open cover $\mathcal{V}$ is called a refinement of $\mathcal{U}$ if for each $U\in \mathcal{U}$ there exists some $V\in \mathcal{V}$ such that $V\subset U$.

To me this second 'definition' seems more natural, is this important?  I guess these defintions are not equivalent but how bad is this definition of mine?

Answer (score 10):

Your definition, while initially tempting, would make $\{X,\emptyset\}$ a refinement of every open cover! Basically, we need to be sure that every piece of a refinement is small relative to the original cover, and that's what the usual definition gets that yours doesn't. On the other hand, the usual definition does permit, say, $\{X\}$ as a refinement of the cover by all opens: roughly, a refinement doesn't have to be "fine" relative to the small parts of the original cover, but just relative to the big parts. It's a general principle that the small sets in an open cover (i.e. those contained in another element of the cover) are redundant and unimportant.

Comment: Yeah, that's why I thought my definition was better, because of the $\{X\}$ refinement.  Additionally $\mathcal{V}\subset \mathcal{U}$ is a refinement of $\mathcal{U}$ and I don't like that.  In particular, $\mathcal{V}=\emptyset$ is (vacuously) a refinement... I really don't like that.  Yes, a lot of it has to do with the fact that you can't spell refinement without fine.

Comment: No, $\{\emptyset\}$ is not a refinement of any cover of any nonempty space. Don't forget $\mathcal{V}$ has to be a cover-that's important! And note that $\{X\}$ is only a refinement of a cover that already includes $X$, so this might not be as bad as it looks.

Comment: Very true, thanks.

Comment: That is two very enlightening arguments, thanks for sharing!! +1

Comment: PS: Why did you consider $\{X,\varnothing\}$ instead of $\{X\}$ for the first argument? It seems $\varnothing$ plays no argumentative/demonstrative role here, or did I miss something?

Comment: The empty set plays an important role for $\{X, \emptyset\}$ to be a refinement of $\mathcal{U}$ for \textbf{any} $\mathcal{U}$ (if $X$ is an open set) according to the 2nd defiition. For the 2nd def. to be satisfied "for each $U\in\mathcal{U}$ there must exist some $V\in\mathcal{V}$ such that $V\subset U$." This holds trivially for $V=\emptyset$, but it will only hold for $V=X$ if every $U$ is a superset of $X$